# An Error for SigningConfig container type org.gradle.api.internal.FactoryNamedDomainObjectContainer

Tags: android, build.gradle

when trying to build my mobile game I got this message:

> Could not get unknown property 'release' for SigningConfig container of type org.gradle.api.internal.FactoryNamedDomainObjectContainer.

However have tried some solutions but they seems to not work or I can't find/missing? The that some seems to have: signingConfigs {
        myconfig {
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            storeFile file('xxx')
            storePassword 'xxx'
        }
    }

Here is part of the CordovaLib build.gradle:

```
android {
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        }
    addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
}
if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)


compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion
publishNonDefault true

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
    }
```

I appreciate help to solv this error.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Put the signingsConfigs before the buildTypes.

I.E.

```
   android {
        signingConfigs {
        //Your configuration here
       }
       buildTypes {
          release {
               signingConfig signingConfigs.release
              }
         }
    }
```

Comment: In my case, I had to put it above productFlavors. Basically, check where the signingConfigs is first referred in your app bundle, and put the signingConfigs above that.